# how to save id from one service to another using select in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, select, save, angular-ngmodel

I want to save the id I get from one service in another using select this is my method

```
<select class="form-control" id="select_fac" [(ngModel)]="rep.idfac">
                <option selected disabled>Select the company</option>
                <option *ngFor="let fact of factory" [ngValue]="fact.id_fac">{{fact.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

I have this in my component.ts

```
 factory: Factory[]=[];
 rep:Representative= new Representative();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ReactiveForms:
[Angular Docs: Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

You can bind the data with formContralName